# How to get clicked sap.m.Table - Item data from sap.m.Menu - used as context menu?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a sap.m.Table in my View with some Items.
Now I have implemetned sap.m.Menu as a context menu to this table.

Am I able to get the Table Item a clicked in menuItemPressed event of the sap.m.MenuItem?

Example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/dusansacha/Lbgja7r8/37/

```
    onInit: function() {
      
      function menuItemPressed(oEvent) {
      
        console.log(oEvent.getSource().getId());
        
        console.log(oEvent.getSource().getParent().getId());
                
        // How to get selected Table-ColumnListItem information?
        console.log(oEvent.getSource().getParent().getParent().getId());
      }
      
      this.getView().byId("idTable").setContextMenu(
        new sap.m.Menu({
         items: [
                    new sap.m.MenuItem({text: "Menu Item1", press: menuItemPressed}),
                    new sap.m.MenuItem({text: 'Menu Item2', press: menuItemPressed})
            ]
        }));
    
    
    }
```

One solution which came to my mind is to use Custom Data on sap.m.MenuItem. But this seems not right for me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In your `onInit` function you can attach the `beforeOpenContextMenu` event as follows:

```
this.getView().byId("idTable").attachBeforeOpenContextMenu((event) => {
 //do something useful with event.getParameter("listItem")
});
```

This event is fired when the context menu is opened. When the context menu is opened, the binding context of the item is set to the given contextMenu (from the documentation).
For further reference, here the link to the [API reference](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Table%23events/beforeOpenContextMenu)

Comment: Thanks. Ok, I can get the context when the menu is opened.
However I am still not able to get the context when the Menu Item is clicked.

Comment: @sachad I don't have a better idea right now but you could store the context in `this._oRightClickedRow` and then access it in your `menuItemPressed` event.

Comment: @Marc exactly :)